# Select Box Populated From Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu, html-table, auto-populate

I currently have a table sorted/filtered by several select boxes and two radio buttons, and it is working fine. I would the select boxes to be automatically populated from a table. Specifically, I would like a state select box that is populated from the States in my Articles table. I currently have an articles.rb model and state.rb model, and I have the relationships set up. article belongs_to :state, state has_many :article. Here is my code so far:

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag articles_path, :method => "GET" do %>

  <%= radio_button_tag :gender_search, "M" %>
  <%= label_tag :gender_search_M, "M" %>
  <%= radio_button_tag :gender_search, "F" %>
  <%= label_tag :gender_search_F, "F" %>

  <%= select_tag :state_search, options_for_select([['Select a state', 0],['-----------', 0],['LA', 'LA'],['MS', 'MS'], ['TX', 'TX']], @prev_state) %>
  <%= select_tag :city_search, options_for_select([['Select a city', 0],['----------', 0],['Mandeville', 'Mandeville'],['Covington', 'Covington']], @prev_city) %>

  <%= submit_tag "Go" %>

<% end %>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered span8 table-condensed" id="articles_table">
  <thead class="header">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Created_At</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render @articles %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**_article.html.erb**

```
<tr>
  <td> <%= article_counter +1 %> </td>
  <td> <%= article.Title %> </td>
  <td> <%= article.Description %> </td>
  <td> <%= article.Created_At %> </td>
</tr>
```

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state


def self.city_search(city_search)
    if city_search
      where('City LIKE ?', "%#{city_search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
end
def self.state_search(state_search)
    if state_search
      where('State LIKE ?', "%#{state_search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
end
```

Please let me know if I need to post any more code or any more information. Anything that could help me would be great.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: I have not tried the answer yet. I will once I get home today @MrYoshiji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this website:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

I figured out that I actually did not need to have models set up for State and City. All I needed to do was make a collection_select that selected the Distinct States from my Articles table. Here is what it looks like:

```
<%= collection_select :article, :state, Article.select(:state).uniq.order('state ASC'), :state, :state, {:prompt => 'Select a State'},{:name => "state_search"} %>
```

So all I had to do was set up the collection_select like the website said and add **Article.select(:state).uniq.order('state ASC')** as my collection to select the uniq states from my Articles table.

Answer (score 2):

Worth taking a look at

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

I think for states you could do something like

```
<%= collection_select :state_id, State.all, :id, :name, multiple: true, :prompt => "Please Select" %>
```

Now that may not be exact but its how im doing it in my app and it works (though country rather than state)

Comment: I am not using f.collection_select, because all of my other ones do not use f, instead I tried using just collection_select, but it returns the error **undefined method `map' for :id:Symbol**. Do you know why?

Comment: sorry i shouldn’t have used f, that was because i was passing f through my block on work i was currently doing at the time. Is your state model full of pre populated data?

Comment: It isn't. Do I need to populate it manually or is there a way for it to always be populated by the states in the articles table?

Comment: yes the table need to pre populated with the data, try having a look for a gem with states of America, should be a few out there

Comment: Ok I will. Is there any way for it to be populated from the States existing in my Articles table?

Comment: not really, as im guessing there are duplicate entries? better to have a clean model with one of each state

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20881/discussion-between-jackadanos-and-richlewis)